# is there any event related to drag over in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I can see there is many events in `fabric js` like,

```
object:modified
object:rotating
object:scaling
object:moving
object:selected
before:selection:cleared
selection:cleared
selection:created
path:created
mouse:down
mouse:move
mouse:up
mouse:over
mouse:out
```

But, i cant found any event related to `mouse drag over`.
Is there any event exist related to that?

Comment: What event are you searching for exactly? Describe the event you're searching for.

Comment: similar `nousedragover` @leroydev

Comment: That's not a description.

Answer (score 1):

Hi , Seems like there is  no suchlike events in Fabricjs, But I recommend you to use  as below.

```
          var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("canvas-container");
          canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);

             function handleDragOver(e) {
                    if (e.preventDefault) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }

                    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
                    return false;
                }
```